# Getting Flash Error #2048 when trying to use WatchESPN.com on Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, 64-bit, flash

When I try to use WatchESPN.com on Chrome I get "Error #2048" in the Flash window and nothing renders.  Strangely enough it works completely fine in Firefox.  I do have some extensions that might mess with it (Ghostery, Adbock) but I even tried whitelisting ESPN on both extensions (disabling them) and it still doesn't work.  I tried searching Google for this error but it was less than helpful.

Windows 7 x64
Latest Chrome

Let me know if you need any more details.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was having the same issue and it was being caused by HTTPS Everywhere which forces an HTTPS connection.

Comment: That was it! Thanks a ton, that was driving me crazy.  For the record I found out it was just the Adobe rule, only had to uncheck that on HTTPS Everywhere; no need to shut the whole extension down: https://i.imgur.com/ogGftYf.png